# Get UTC time from Openfire server

Tags: ios, openfire, utc, xmppframework

I am using openfire server for my chat application in iOS. My problem is, I could not get utc time from my xmpp message. Is there any support from openfire for this, getting standard utc time irrespect of device local time ? Any help is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: see this link here, its giving the datetime format. Hopefully this should be server time.
https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/util/FastDateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.util.TimeZone, java.util.Locale)

Comment: How can I obtain these values from my xcode project?